# is there a way to get higher precision with pyspark greater than 38?

Tags: python, pyspark, precision, aws-glue

using pyspark and glue jobs, it seems there is a max precision of 38.  lots of crypto systems need greater precision.  is there a way around this to increase precision without having to use an entirely different system?

Answer (score 3):

38 is the max precision for a Spark Decimal, since they use Java's BigDecimal Implementation under the hood.

If you need to calculate with a higher precision, I think you need to look for an alternative. I am not aware of any workarounds.